# zend framework 2 with doctrine 2 $form->getData() in controller not returning all fields set using $form->setData()

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have set my form for validation using `$form->setData()`.
After validation I am not receiving all of my properties back using `$form->getData()`.

I am using following lines in controller
and somehow `$form->getData()` is not returning all fields anyone has any idea why?

```
 if ($request->isPost()) 
 {  
   $company = new Company();   
   $form->setInputFilter($company->getInputFilter());                        
   $form->setData($request->getPost()); 
   print_r($request->getPost());      // getPost shows all fields fine  
   if ($form->isvalid()) 
   {                   
      print_r($form->getData()); // is returning only select and text type fields which are in input filter. why?
   }
}
```

my form is looks like this.

```
class Companyform extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {        
        parent::__construct('company');

        $this->setAttribute ('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute ('class', 'form-horizontal');

        $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'id',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'hidden'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add ( array (
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',        
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'title',
                'options' => array(                    
                    'mr' => 'Mr',
                    'miss' => 'Miss',
                    'mrs' => 'Mrs',
                    'dr' => 'Dr'
                ),
                'value' => 'mr'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Title'
            )
        ));


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'fname',            
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'fname',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "First Name",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'First Name'
            )

        ));



        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'surname',            
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'surname',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "Surname Name",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Surname Name'
            )

        ));  


        $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'companyName',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'companyName',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "Company Name",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Company Name'
            )


        ));


        $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'address1',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'address1',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "Address Line 1",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Address'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'address2',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'address2',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "Address Line 2",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Address'
            )
        ));


        $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'address3',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'address3',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => "Address Line 3",
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Address'
            )
        ));
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'btnsubmit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'btnsubmit',
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Add',   
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ),
        ));

    }

}
```

and This is the input filter which I am using in entity company

```
public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
{
    throw new \Exception("Not used");
}

public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        $factory = new InputFactory();

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'companyName',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));



        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every single Form-Element has to get validated! Even if the validator is empty like

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'title'
)));
```

Only validated data get's passed from the form.

Comment: if that is the case, I could get my head around why it showing SELECT type elements without adding them in the filter?

Comment: Well, my guess would be that select elements do have pre-defined data. Yet again this alone shouldn't be trusted, i agree with that. Though this is just what i know. Only validated data gets through for me.

Comment: If you are not sure about answer, add it under comments not answer

Comment: No worries, not trying to help you again ;)